# Require authorization active_admin/devise in controller :only index show edit destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I am trying to require an authorization in my controller called purcahses_controller.rb It's just an order form model with Show Edit Destroy.. I can view it in active_admin, the url being localhost/admin/purchases. But the problem is I can also view it at localhost/purchases. It lists all of the orders and allows all functions. Id like to route_to rooturl with a simple unauthorized message if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a routing issue, what does your route look like for the purchase model?

Comment: @kevinb - Well I have tried several methods with a before_filter and trying to def authorization, but I was getting more lost. So instead, I guess I'm asking how would I include a before_filter in my controller for Activeadmin to be required :only for those ones that need to be required. Which is everything except creating the order.

Comment: Here is what I did. I added 

          before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter do 
    redirect_to :new_user_session_path unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end

And it sends them to sign in. But instead of the activeadmin sign in it's a different sign in. It's going to /users/sign_in instead of /admin/login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following and it will give you option to redirect to any path you see fit.

In the file

> config/initializers/active_admin.rb

Make the following change

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_active_admin_user!
```

Then inside your application controller adding something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def authenticate_active_admin_user!
    authenticate_user!
    unless current_user.superadmin?
      flash[:alert] = "Unauthorized Access!"
      redirect_to "/admin/login"
    end
  end
end
```

In your purchases_controller add the following before_filter line:

```
before_filter :authenticate_active_admin_user!
```

Hopefully this helps!
~Kevin

Comment: No errors @kevin but it's not asking for redirecting me to login. It still displays data

Comment: Did you add the following line in your purchases controller?
before_filter :authenticate_active_admin_user!
Add that line in any controller you want to "lock" down

Comment: Okay, I did this, and it's doing what it did to me before. Redirecting me to a /users/sign_in instead of the /admin/login page

Comment: but I did forget to put that line in purchases controller. Do you know what could be over riding this?

Comment: that is the right answer. I must have some other user table and configuration set up over riding the active admin one? I genereated this app, with a user model and everything packaged. So maybe if I find out what it is and remove it, do you think then this would fix it?

Comment: for some reason my :except => or :only isn't preventing authentication from being bypassed

Comment: i got it fixed pretty much. tweaked a little bit and voila.

Answer (score 0):

`authenticate_active_admin_user` gives you access to the admin authenticate user which will lead you to the authorization regardless of what you call in admin.

```
controller do 
  skip_before_action :authenticate_active_admin_user, only: :action
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nsm-activeadmin/0.2.2/ActiveAdmin%2FResourceController%3Aauthenticate_active_admin_user

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb#L38